# Center items in last row using CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to center the bottom two li items (restaurant info containers in the image below) in a ul list that is set to `display: grid`. I thought adding `justify-items: center` to the ul list ruleset would work, but it didn't. I also tried `justify-content: center`, which didn't change anything. Is there a solution that works with CSS grid that would the items in the last row?

[image: appearance]

```
<ul id="restaurants-list"></ul>
```

```
/* ul element */
#restaurants-list {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 15px 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-items: center;
}

#restaurants-list li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 270px;
}
```

Comment: share full code

Comment: css without HTML is useless ... we don't need full CSS, but we need the necessary code (html + css) that reproduce your issue

Comment: This should work: #restaurants-list li:nth-last-child(2) { grid-column-start: 2; }

Answer (score 1):

`justify-items: center;` aligns element **inside its grid cell** - has nothing with alignment items in a row.

I'd suggest to do not use `display:grid` here but rather `display:inline-block` elements like this:

```
#restaurants-list {
   display:block;
   text-align: center;
   ...
}

#restaurants-list > li {
   display:inline-block;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks. I'm relying on CSS grid in my media queries so am looking for a solution that works with it if there is any way to center items in the last row.